# How to import a module?

Tags: eclipse, acceleo

What is the right way to import a module?

I have a main modul called `DatabaseGenerator`. It's located under `eu.the4thfloor.dme.generator.main.DatabaseGenerator.mtl`

I have another modul called `DatabaseGeneratorHelper`. This is located under `eu.the4thfloor.dme.generator.common.DatabaseGeneratorHelper.mtl`

Now I want to import the helper module with this command:

```
[import eu::the4thfloor::dme::generator::common::DatabaseGeneratorHelper /]
```

I get no error in the modul files but I get a error from Eclipse:

```
Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Acceleo Builder' on project 'eu.the4thfloor.dme.generator'.
org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceException: Resource '/dme.generator/bin/eu/the4thfloor/dme/generator/common/DatabaseGeneratorHelper.emtl' does not exist.
```

But the files exist. Whats going wrong?

And is it right that the helper modul does not have xml files in the task folder?

Ralph

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried running "Project clean" in Eclipse?

Make sure you have your .mtl in the package: eu.the4thfloor.dme.generator.common

If so, I would try...

- Delete DatabaseGeneratorHelper.java
- F5 in the root project.
- Project clean.
- Make a change in the .mtl (for example, white space) and save the
  file.
- Run acceleo with your ordinary config.

Sometimes, Acceleo makes strange things because of errors in compiled files... but after this sequence everything usually works perfect.

PS: I would like to post a comment but I haven't got enought points

Comment: Unfortunately, the 'magic trick' of cleaning and recompiling does not work. I have the same problem and tried almost everyhting. It seems that it is a simple matter, but not cleaning and recompiling.

Comment: You can try this too: In your plugin config ("plugin.xml"), mark the package which gives you the error problem, the one with templates, as "exported packages" in "runtime" tab. Maybe this would help ;)

Comment: I guess with "plugin.xml" you refer to "MANIFEST.MF" file (Runtime tab is here). I tried this and still not working. 
Did you ever do an "import" and it worked succesfully?

Comment: An example of an empty project doing an import and in which I get the error can be found here: https://www.wetransfer.com/downloads/a4aa90e671e5f442a36e5f66db8387c920150202121859/f3f8882b6ef32d13138c9bfe23561d7420150202121859/90886d

Comment: I tried to fix your project but after one and a half hour I have't got to the solution. The cause is that your project is searching the generated files (emtl) in a path that not exists (but it does!). Nevermind, I've created a project for you with two templates (one imports the other) without errors. I hope this would help you: here you are https://www.wetransfer.com/downloads/f702b8fad1b4f041ef5c0f4e96de0ea720150202144145/70bcac18dd6a040807b12af535b5d7c420150202144145/b05fe3

Comment: that's crazy man. I imported your project and it works fine. I added new modules to your project and it worked fine. I was searching for differences for more than an hour, no luck. Same structure, same content.

Then, I created an exact copy of your project using my eclipse, and it does not work.
Then, I put your project into the same folder, imported it, and it worked fine. I changed the package names, and it worked fine. WTF Eclipse? The char encoding is the last property to check... U.U

Anyway, thank you very much for your time. Mil gracias tío!!

Comment: I swear you I haven't done any hidden trick nor anything else.. haha. Feel free to ask whatever you need. De nada ;)

Answer (score 1):

Definitely I think I solved the problem.

Acceleo requires that the name of your project in your workspace (i.e., the one you can see in the Package Explorer in the left tab in Eclipse) needs to be EXACTLY THE SAME as the name of the folder containing the project in your file system.

It seems that Acceleo compiler uses the name in the workspace instead the real containing folder's name during compilation, which may be a bug of the compiler since Acceleo projects with a different name are not allowed.